# Writing an R function that evens out both sides of equation

Tags: r, function

I am quite new to r, so I turned to the internet for some help.

My question is:

for the equation ***ln(n/n0) = k*ln(1+x/k)**, 
I would like to write a function that estimates k (based of trial and error)  if all other variables are known.

In other words: function that would solve the equation like 
0.85 = k * ln(1+0.56/k).

In my work I have to estimate k over and over again so the automation of the process would save me alot of time.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `uniroot`: `uniroot(function(k) k * log(1 + 0.56/k) - 0.85, c(-1, -.9))` but you'll have to set the bounds to avoid the discontinuities, which makes programmatic usage useless unless you can figure out the asymptotes programmatically, too.

Comment: alistaire thank you, problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment...
The equation `x*ln(1+a/x) = b` (for suitable values of `a` and `b`) has a solution expressed with the Lambert *W* function, available in the `gsl` package under the name `lambert_W0`. This solution is `-a*b/(a*W(-b/(a*exp(b/a)))+b)` where `W` is the Lambert *W* function.

```
> library(gsl)
> a=0.56; b=0.85
> x <- -a*b/(a*lambert_W0(-b/(a*exp(b/a)))+b) # solution of the equation
> x*log(1+a/x)
[1] 0.85
```

I don't know exactly for which values of `a` and `b` this solution works. It seems to work whenever `a<b`.

For *some* cases of `a>b`, there is a solution in terms of the Lambert *W_{-1}* function, `lambert_Wm1` in `gsl`:

```
> library(gsl)
> a=0.6; b=0.4
> x <- -a*b/(a*lambert_Wm1(-b/(a*exp(b/a)))+b)
> x*log(1+a/x)
[1] 0.4
```

The domains of definition of *W* and *W_{-1}* can be found in the [documentation of the `lamW` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lamW/lamW.pdf) (section "Details" page 3).

Comment: Stéphane Laurent thanks for complexly elegant solution. But I noticed that the expression for finding x does not work correctly if a > b. Can I change the expression so that it also works when a > b

Comment: @GregorS I tried with Wolfram for some values a>b. It does not give an exact solution. So it's probably not possible.

Comment: @GregorS See my edit. Sometimes there is a solution. It suffices to replace "W zero" with "W minus one".

Comment: If all you need is real-values Lambert W functions, I believe the implementation in `lamW` is faster than that in `gsl` (especially for vectors of losses as it's parallelized) but I haven't explicitly timed it.